# In R : translate GLMM models into mathematical notation (using Gamma family and log)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, logarithm, notation

I have those two following generalized linear mixed models. The object Sbiomass is modeled as the sum of biomass in several replicas. The objects x1 and x3 are discrete variables, x1 is a continuous variable.

```r
glmmTMB(log(Sbiomass) ~ x1 + (1 | x1/x3), data = mydata)

glmmTMB(Sbiomass ~ poly(distance,3) + (1|x1) + exp(x2 + 0|x3), 
    family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = mydata)
```

What does those equations look like in mathematical notation?

Comment: Use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equatiomatic/index.html

Comment: @FlorianHartig I believe tha the package equatiomatic does not allow GLMM model, or any random effect at all

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/equatiomatic/vignettes/lme4-lmer.html for random effects. Might not work directly with glmmTMB (never tried it), but the basic model structure and exposition in terms of equations should be the same.